# Detect whether process is system process or not

Tags: android

I am using this method to get running processes

```
private void getRunningProcess() {
    {PackageManager pm=getActivity().getPackageManager();
    final ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (runningProcesses != null && runningProcesses.size() > 0) {
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity(), runningProcesses));
    }
    }
```

I am getting all processes but I want to show only non-system processes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  

List<RunningAppProcessInfo> run = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

try it!

Comment: That's what I am actually doing !! I am getting all processes including System processes .I want to get only non system Processes.